# return in eventhandler function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Following code is not working and not returning proper result.

```
function test(file) {
 var uri = "http://localhost/test.php";
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var result="done";
 xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
 xhr.send();
 xhr.onloadend=function()
  {
   result=xhr.responseText;
   return result;
  }
}
```

Is it wrong to return from event handlers or it just returns result back to test function?

Comment: More than one question for one problem? Your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847432/xmlhttprequest-object-working-but-not-giving-output-in-response just 14 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

returning in an event handler, as you are doing, will not return results back to the calling scope. The DOM event function you are using to attach the listener to disregards the return value.
If you are trying to access the result from onload you will need to do so in a callback

```
function test(file, callback){
    var uri = "http://localhost/test.php";  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open("POST", uri, true);  
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onload=function(){
        callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to return from event handlers, but your return value doesn't go where you apparently think it goes. In most cases, event handlers are expected to only return `true` or `false`, which indicates whether you want to disable the default behavior or not (`false` means "suppress the default behavior for this event"). It is not possible to receive the return value of your `onloadend` handler in either your `test()` function or as a return value of your `test()` function, because the event handler is executed asynchronously, at a time when your function has already returned.